# How to find yellow objects on given picture?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

I've this picture:
[image]

(this is just subimage of bigger image but only this part is for me important). I need algorithm for finding all these yellow objects in the image and find from them the object which contains the most yellow points. This is just one picture of thousands of similar pictures with more or less these yellow objects. What is the way to do this? I found that the scanline algorithm is good for this, but I haven't found some example which would help me. If you have some ideas or even algorithm it would be perfect. Those color lines are not important I just put them as some border in which I need to find the yellow objects.

Thanks a lot for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic steps:

- **Thresholding:** Generate an array of yellow and not-yellow pixels. If the images you're working with are all like the example you provided, this should be very easy, but try adaptive thresholding if you have to deal with varying shades and hues. Store, e.g., a value of -1 for pixels that are yellow, and 0 everywhere else.
- **Segmentation:** Initialize an ID value to 1. Scan every pixel of the thresholded image. When you encounter a pixel with a value of -1 (i.e., a yellow pixel), use a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) routine to write the ID value into this pixel and all the yellow pixels connected to it. Before the flood fill routine exits, you can store information such as the number of pixels it found and the average X and Y coordinates in an array indexed by the ID value. Then increment the ID value and resume scanning until you've covered the entire image.

Then search the data generated by the flood fill routine to find which yellow areas were the largest, and where they were located.

[Here's a program that does something quite similar with red objects instead of yellow ones, and then draws circles around them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20033/11006).

[image: red circles around things]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like OpenCV has blob detection options. I found this article showing how to detect the blobs using greyscale value, which you should be able to change to use the color value of your target color. It also mentions using the area of the blob as a threshold, so you should be able to use that to find the largest one in the image.

http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to generate a quad-tree of the image. Using this quad-tree it's pretty simple to find conjunct pieces that form a blob (even with holes) and calculate the size of these.